# Disabling HTTP GET/POST in Spring

Tags: spring, rest

I have a Spring application which is based on REST APIs. I would like to disable HTTP GET/POST methods but would like to allow HTTPS GET/POST methods.

How can I do that ?

Comment: Do you use spring boot?

Comment: Nope I am using Spring 4.0

Answer (score 4):

Simply add the following to your application.properties :

```
server.port: 8443
server.ssl.key-store: classpath:keystore.p12
server.ssl.key-store-password: password
server.ssl.keyStoreType: PKCS12
server.ssl.keyAlias: tomcat
```

Then generate a certificate to test

```
keytool -genkey -alias tomcat -storetype PKCS12 -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -keystore keystore.p12 -validity 3650
```

Add the keystore.p12 to src/main/resources so it is added to the jar

Here is an integration test via https:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
public class HelloControllerIT {

    @LocalServerPort
    private int port;

    private RestTemplate template;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        createTemplateFromKeyStore("keystore.p12");
    }

    @Test
    public void getHello() throws Exception {
        ResponseEntity<String> response = template.getForEntity("https://localhost:" + port + "/", String.class);
        assertThat(response.getBody(), equalTo("Greetings from Spring Boot!"));
    }

    private void createTemplateFromKeyStore(String keyStoreName) {
        try {
            InputStream keyStoreInputStream = getClass().getResourceAsStream(keyStoreName);
            KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
            keyStore.load(keyStoreInputStream, null);

            SSLContext sslContext = org.apache.http.ssl.SSLContexts.custom()
                    .loadKeyMaterial(keyStore, "password".toCharArray())
                    .loadTrustMaterial(keyStore, new TrustAllStrategy()).build();

            HttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom().setSSLContext(sslContext)
                    .setSSLHostnameVerifier(NoopHostnameVerifier.INSTANCE).build();

            HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory();
            requestFactory.setHttpClient(httpClient);

            template = new RestTemplate(requestFactory);
        } catch (IOException | GeneralSecurityException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I already have https enabled but the problem is that someone can make a GET/POST request on http also which I wanted to prevent.

Comment: I get Bad Request
This combination of host and port requires TLS. if I try http

Comment: does it matter if my alias is tomcat or not?

Comment: @naoru it's just a simple name/tag that is used to identify the certificate in a keystore may contain many certificates. You can use any name you like. Good explanation [here](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/123944/what-is-the-purpose-role-of-the-alias-attribute-in-java-keystore-files)

Answer (score 0):

Make your server only "HTTPS" enable and block "HTTP" request on server level. on application level HTTP request blocking is bad practice.